# Outlook Anywhere settings changed

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365, outlook-anywhere

I have accidentally changed the Outlook Anywhere settings in Exchange 2013 and didnt make a note! any ideas as to what the original settings should be ? we access outlook web access within the business via `https://owa.example.co.uk/owa`

All our email addresses are   via `firstname.lastname@example.co.uk`

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I prepare for our cutover migration to Exchange 365.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the virtual directory back to default, then it will be a hostname that is on your SSL certificate - so mail.example.co.uk - nothing more complicated than that.